# gVIM on Windows: execute buffer and paths with spaces

Tags: windows, vim, quotes

In gVim for windows it's possible to execute current buffer via :!% command. But, unfortunately, the buffer file name is supplied to cmd.exe without quotes, so if file path has spaces gVim will not be able to execute it.

Is it any easy way to fix it in order to be able execute .bat, .py etc from within gVim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This's my guess, I don't have windows machine to try. Try

```
:!python "%"
```

or

```
:!"%"
```

credit: Eye of Hell

Comment: :!"%" was a success :). Please change your answer for future :)