# Using filepaths with spaces in gVim and Windows 7

Tags: vim, windows-7

This is my path copied from the context menu Windows Explorer: `"C:\Vim Python\getTime.py"` and I'm trying to use The Vim Expression Register as seen in Derek Wyatt's [blog](http://www.derekwyatt.org/vim/vim-tutorial-videos/vim-advanced-tutorial-videos/) to insert output from a given Python script into a buffer.

I've tried all combinations I can think of slashes and quotes to get the following command to bind `<c-j>d`to insert the output of the script like so:

`imap <c-j>d <c-r>=system("C:\Vim Python\getTime.py")<cr>`

but I can't seem to get it working without having it insert the following error:

`'C:\Vim' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

What do I need to change in order to use a filepath with spaces in it?

If you'd like to see what I've tried, take a look at the [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/bdYK5rc4) for a good laugh. The searches I've done lead me to a [few](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Backslash-spaces-in-windows-path-td1193484.html) [different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531232/gvim-on-windows-execute-buffer-and-paths-with-spaces) [places](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Annoying-spaces-in-Path-td1171981.html), but none of them solved my issue, or at least, I didn't read them correctly.

---

The correct solution for me was:

```
imap <c-j>d <c-r>=system(shellescape('C:\Vim Python\getTime.py'))<cr>
```

Thanks to [Chiel here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12698017/541208)

Comment: Prefer `:inoremap` over `:imap`, unless you really need remapping of the RHS. It avoids interference with other mappings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the shellescape function of vim.
Type `:help shellescape` in vim to get specific info.

So changing your line to `imap <c-j>d <c-r>=system(shellescape("C:\Vim Python\getTime.py"))<cr>` should do the job.

Comment: And either use single quotes around the path, and/or use forward slashes (`C:/Vim Python/getTime.py`), as the backslash escapes `\t` into `<Tab>` when used in double-quoted strings.

Comment: Thanks, `imap <c-j>d <c-r>=system(shellescape('C:\Vim Python\getTime.py'))<cr>
` worked, with single quotes.